# Somar Array vindo de vários campos

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário com vários campos contendo valores em moeda como posso somar todos esses valores na saida do post

Exemplo form

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" action="includes/acao.php?form=faturamento"   
method="post" >
<input type='hidden' name='valor[{$id_finan}]'  value='{960.00}' />
<input type='hidden' name='valor[{$id_finan}]'  value='{960.00}' />
<input type='hidden' name='valor[{$id_finan}]'  value='{960.00}' />
</form
```

acao.php

```
foreach($_POST["checkbox"] as $key=>$value){    
echo $valor = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['valor'][$key]);
// Retorno 960.00960.00960.00
}
```

Como trazer esse retorno ja somado

Comment: Você quer somar antes de chegar no servidor, é isso? No evento `submit` do form você pode fazer isso.

Comment: Prefiro que a soma seje feita no acao.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só para complementar com outra alternativa, dessa vez usando o foreach:

```
$post = array(
    'valor' => array(
        0 => 10,
        1 => 10,
        3 => 10,
    )
);  
$soma = 0;
foreach ($post['valor'] as $key => $value) {
    $soma += $value;
}

echo $soma //30
```

Eu iria de array_sum;

Comment: Show Isso Mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

```
# SIMULACAO
$post = array(
    'valor' => array(
        0 => 10,
        1 => 10,
        3 => 10,
        4 => 10,
        5 => 10,
        6 => 10,
        7 => 10,
    )
);

# RESOLUCAO
echo array_sum($post['valor']); // 70
```

Comment: Não conhecia essa outra maneira de somar os elementos de tipo numérico dentro de um array. +1

Answer (score 4):

Resolução:

```
$length_array = count($_POST['valor']);
$soma = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $length_array; $i++){
    $soma = $soma + $_POST['valor'][$i];
}

echo 'A soma é: '.$soma;
```

Ou dentro do laço de repetição (for):

```
$soma += $_POST['valor'][$i];
```

Referências:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.assignment.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php